# 3-Day Passes available for New York Comic Con 2012, October 12-14

Tags: discussion, community-event

**UPDATE:** All 3-day passes have been claimed. Thank you to everyone who claimed a pass. See you at the con!

---

[New York Comic Con](http://www.newyorkcomiccon.com/) is soon approaching (October 12-14). For any users interested in attending, Stack Exchange has 3-day passes available. Please note that **Stack Exchange is only providing 3-day passes**; **we are not responsible for travel or lodging**.

Those receiving a 3-day pass will get a Stack Exchange NYCC swag package, including a SciFi.SE shirt, stickers and lanyard to use at the con and, also, your day-to-day existence. I will try to switch out the SciFi shirt with an Arqade one, if possible (only if because I'm not sure what we have in office currently :) )

For a pass, please e-mail the following information to **brett [at] stackexchange [dot] com** with the title **NYCC 2012**:

1. Your name
2. Your username
3. Your mailing address
4. Your t-shirt size

Stack Exchange will also have a booth on the show floor this year (Booth #2278). Employees from the Community Growth team and other departments will be at the booth, and our **[famous (?) Spinning Wheel](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/heroescon-2012-report/)** will also be distributing prizes to all who spin it.

Thanks!

Comment: If I didn't already have plans... Ah, well!  More for other people!

Comment: It really sucks being on the other side of the ocean...

Comment: ah, too bad october is such a bad month this year for me, already traveling the week before and after comic con

Comment: Can SE also pay to move the event to London? KTHXBAI

Comment: Clearly @fredley misspelled "Dallas", but that's okay, it happens.